# About Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My Rails4 app has some routes

```
get '/mem(/:id)(/:action)(.format)' ,:controller=>'sns_mem',id: /\d+/
get '/group(/:id)(/:action)(.format)' ,:controller=>'sns_group',id: /\d+/
get '/article(/:id)(/:action)(.format)' ,:controller=>'sns_article',id: /\d+/
get '/photo(/:id)(/:action)(.format)' ,:controller=>'sns_photo',id: /\d+/
```

As you can see,these routes are similar,so I want to know how to merge these routes to one?

Comment: you are right,I mean these route format is similar ,so I want to know whether the RegExp can reach this?

Comment: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: But I didn't found the answer to merge these routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
['mem', 'group', 'article', 'photo'].each do |r|
    get "/#{r}(/:id)(/:action)(.format)" ,:controller=>"sns_#{r}",id: /\d+/
end
```

Never tried with loops in routes.rb file, but should work.
It is not properly ONE route, it will create one route for each element of the array, but at least you will avoid typos. Moreover, regexp are generally slower.